# Get column type using full table path name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a column type in SQL server. I know that this works just fine:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' and COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name';
```

But it doesn't work with

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '[database_name].[dbo].[table_name]' and COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name';
```

This is part of a stored procedure that is in a different database and I would like to be able to pass it full the full path name so it can run from whatever database I am in.

Comment: The table name is just the name without the schema and database.  You cannot generally do what you want, because `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is *within* a database (not a server).  `OBJECT_ID` might help.

Comment: You need to query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view from the database that you want: `FROM database_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the database name in front of INFORMATION_SCHEMA as a qualifier.  If you aren't hard-coding it, you'll need to use dynamic SQL.  But "DbName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" will get you to the right system view (on the same server), and then the TABLE_NAME = x and COLUMN_NAME = y will get you to the table and column.

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
    FROM THEOTHERDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' and COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the other way round!
You need to query the information_schema obects in the other DB

EG SElect * from OtherDB.information_schema.columns